# ConfigurationSection deserialisation to concrete type

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config, wcf-security, wif

I have a config file with `IdentityConfiguration` information in it which I am using for securing my WCF Services e.g.

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
          <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <trustedIssuers>
              <add thumbprint="4459.....5E4" name="adfs" />
              <add thumbprint="85BBD0....94A4C7" name="identityServer" />
            </trustedIssuers>
          </issuerNameRegistry>
        </securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://Iamauri/services"/>
      </audienceUris>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
```

I would like to deserialize the above in to an `IdentityConfiguration` object but I can't figure out how to go from a `ConfigurationSection` representing the above information to a concrete type.

What I have so far:

> var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
>                       new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
>
> var s = (SystemIdentityModelSection) config.GetSection("system.identityModel");
>
> // TODO: Deserialize s to IdentityConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

If you have that configuration in your app.config file, the correct handler for the configuration section will be automatically used so you shouldn't have to do anything beyond calling `IdentityConfiguration.LoadConfiguration()` which should return the object you are looking for.

More info at: [System.IdentityModel.Configuration.IdentityConfiguration.LoadConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.configuration.identityconfiguration.loadconfiguration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Edit after comment:**

If you are manually working with the `SystemIdentityModelSection` object, you can use the `IdentityConfigurationElements` contained in this object to load an `IdentityConfiguration` by calling `IdentityConfiguration.LoadHandlerConfiguration()`.

More info on this method at: [System.IdentityModel.Configuration.IdentityConfiguration.LoadHandlerConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192510%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this in my question, that's no good for us, we're largely configuring code which means the app.config is completely ignored. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205277(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Updated to show which methods you should use - which element you provide will be an interesting question tho' (unless there is always just one?)